# How to declare multiple header files in a modulemap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, flutter, cocoapods

I have a modulemap that I have declared in my iOS file which is a part of my Flutter plugin but I don't know how to declare multiple header files as 2 header files don't get recognised in my Swift File.

```
module TapjoySDK {
    header "/../../../ios/Pods/TapjoySDK/TapjoySDK_iOS_v12.6.1/Libraries/Tapjoy.embeddedframework/Tapjoy.framework/Headers/Tapjoy.h"
    export *
}

module TapjoyPlacement { //This won't get recognised in my Swift file
        header "/../../../ios/Pods/TapjoySDK/TapjoySDK_iOS_v12.6.1/Libraries/Tapjoy.embeddedframework/Tapjoy.framework/Headers/TJPlacement.h"
        export *
    }
```

This is my `podspec` -

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'flutter_tapjoy'
  s.version          = '1.0.2'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'
  s.dependency 'TapjoySDK'
  s.preserve_path = 'Classes/TapjoySDK/module.modulemap'
  s.static_framework = true
  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice. Only x86_64 simulators are supported.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'x86_64' }
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS' => '$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/Classes/NearbyMessages $(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/Classes' }
end
```